# WSO2 API Manager Store access with Identity Server

Tags: google-api, wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I use [How To Setup a WSO2 API Manager Store Login with Google](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2016/02/article-how-to-setup-a-wso2-api-manager-store-login-with-google/) article for configuring login by Google possibility for WSO2 API Manager Store, but I have a problem.

It seems all working, but I can't login by Google to Store.

1. User automatically created by provisioning.
2. After login clicked, I guess user is logging in to store and logout automatically, probably because have not permissions/roles to login or something else.

How to assign some permissions/roles automatically on user creation after click login by Google?

Maybe problem is in something else?

EDIT:

1. Logs in API Manager:

> TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-09 12:57:52,746]  WARN
>   {org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool} -  maxIdle is larger than
>   maxActive, setting maxIdle to: 40
>   {org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool}
>
> TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-09 12:57:53,486]  WARN {org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool} -  maxIdle is larger than
>   maxActive, setting maxIdle to: 40
>   {org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool}
>
> TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-09 12:57:58,650]  WARN {org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool} -  maxIdle is larger than
>   maxActive, setting maxIdle to: 40
>   {org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool}
>
> TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-09 12:58:23,672] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.permission.update.PermissionUpdater} - 
>   Error when updating the permission cache for tenant : -1
>   {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.permission.update.PermissionUpdater}
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.realm.RegistryRealm.getRealm(RegistryRealm.java:148)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.permission.update.PermissionUpdater.getAuthzManager(PermissionUpdater.java:90)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.permission.update.PermissionUpdater.update(PermissionUpdater.java:60)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.core.util.PermissionUpdateUtil.updatePermissionTree(PermissionUpdateUtil.java:46)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject.jsFunction_updatePermissionCache(APIStoreHostObject.java:743)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>         at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
>         at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
>         at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
>         at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.api.c2._c_anonymous_3(/store/modules/api/permissions.jag:63)
>         at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.api.c2.call(/store/modules/api/permissions.jag)
>         at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
>         at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
>         at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
>         at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
>         at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_14(/store/modules/api/module.jag:48)
>         at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.api.c0.call(/store/modules/api/module.jag)
>         at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
>         at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c1._c_anonymous_1(/store/jagg/jaggery_acs.jag:89)
>         at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c1.call(/store/jagg/jaggery_acs.jag)
>         at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
>         at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c1._c_script_0(/store/jagg/jaggery_acs.jag:5)
>         at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c1.call(/store/jagg/jaggery_acs.jag)
>         at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
>         at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
>         at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c1.call(/store/jagg/jaggery_acs.jag)
>         at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.jagg.c1.exec(/store/jagg/jaggery_acs.jag)
>         at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
>         at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
>         at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:588)
>         at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:508)
>         at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
>         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
>         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:747)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:377)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
>         at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>         at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>         at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
>         at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
>         at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
>         at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>         at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
>         at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
>         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1749)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1708)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-09 12:58:24,029]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.hostobjects.sso.SAMLSSORelyingPartyObject} - 
>   invalidate: Session already invalidated
>   {org.wso2.carbon.hostobjects.sso.SAMLSSORelyingPartyObject}
>
> TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-09 12:58:31,931]  WARN {org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool} -  maxIdle is larger than
>   maxActive, setting maxIdle to: 40
>   {org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool}
>
> TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-09 12:58:34,634]  WARN {org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool} -  maxIdle is larger than
>   maxActive, setting maxIdle to: 40
>   {org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool}

2. Logs in Identity Server:

> TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-09 12:57:42,762]  WARN
>   {org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool} -  maxIdle is larger than
>   maxActive, setting maxIdle to: 40  TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-09
>   12:58:04,670]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.TokenMgtDAO}
>
> - Thread pool size for session persistent consumer : 100  TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-09 12:58:04,986]  INFO
>     {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.policy.finder.CarbonPolicyFinder}
> - Initializing of policy store is started at :  Wed Nov 09 12:58:04 CET 2016  TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-09 12:58:04,993]  INFO
>     {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.policy.store.DefaultPolicyDataStore}
> - Using Global policy combining algorithm that is defined in configuration file.  TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-09 12:58:04,993]  INFO
>     {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.policy.finder.CarbonPolicyFinder}
> - Start retrieving policies from org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.policy.store.RegistryPolicyStoreManageModule@2f8601e6
>     at : Wed Nov 09 12:58:04 CET 2016  TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-09
>     12:58:04,995]  INFO
>     {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.policy.finder.CarbonPolicyFinder}
> - Finish retrieving policies from org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.policy.store.RegistryPolicyStoreManageModule@2f8601e6
>     at : Wed Nov 09 12:58:04 CET 2016  TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-09
>     12:58:04,996]  INFO
>     {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.policy.finder.CarbonPolicyFinder}
> - Initializing of policy store is finished at :  Wed Nov 09 12:58:04 CET 2016  TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-09 12:58:05,035]  INFO
>     {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.policy.finder.CarbonPolicyFinder}
> - Initializing of policy store is started at :  Wed Nov 09 12:58:05 CET 2016  TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-09 12:58:05,036]  INFO
>     {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.policy.store.DefaultPolicyDataStore}
> - Using Global policy combining algorithm that is defined in configuration file.  TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-09 12:58:05,037]  INFO
>     {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.policy.finder.CarbonPolicyFinder}
> - Start retrieving policies from org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.policy.store.RegistryPolicyStoreManageModule@2f8601e6
>     at : Wed Nov 09 12:58:05 CET 2016  TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-09
>     12:58:05,039]  INFO
>     {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.policy.finder.CarbonPolicyFinder}
> - Finish retrieving policies from org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.policy.store.RegistryPolicyStoreManageModule@2f8601e6
>     at : Wed Nov 09 12:58:05 CET 2016  TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-09
>     12:58:05,039]  INFO
>     {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.policy.finder.CarbonPolicyFinder}
> - Initializing of policy store is finished at :  Wed Nov 09 12:58:05 CET 2016  TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-09 12:58:22,983]  INFO
>     {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.permission.update.PermissionUpdater} - 
>     Permission cache updated for tenant -1234

3. Configurations of my Service Provider and Identity Provider are visible below:

[image: Service Provider 1]

[image: Service Provider 2]

[image: Service Provider 3]

[image: Identity Provider 1]

[image: Identity Provider 2]

Comment: Please post error logs if you see any.

Comment: @Bhathiya, updated.

Comment: Since it's an NPE, it's hard to say the exact reason. Please try setting `login` and `subscribe` permissions to internal/everyone role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end of story:

I should use article [Setting up PostgreSQL](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Setting+up+PostgreSQL) especially `Changing the default WSO2_CARBON_DB datasource` for changing default DB to my PostgreSQL DB in API Manager and Identity Server and run server with `-Dserver` option `[For Windows: <PRODUCT_HOME>/bin/wso2server.bat -Dsetup]`.

After all configurations I added permissions `API/Subscribe` and `Login` to `Internal/everyone` role.

Bhathiya, thanks for help. :)